# How to install influxdb and grafana?

Tags: kubernetes

enter image description hereI tried to used the instructions from this link https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/blob/master/docs/influxdb.md but I was not able to install it. specifically I dont know what this instruction means "Ensure that kubecfg.sh is exported." I dont even know where I can find this I did this `sudo find / -name "kubecfg.sh"` and I found no results.

moving on to the next step `"kubectl create -f deploy/kube-config/influxdb/"` when I did this it says kube-system not found I am using latest version of kubernetes version 1.0.1

These instructions are broken can any one provide some instructions on how to install this? I have kubernetes cluster up and running I was able to create and delete pods and so on and **default** is the only namespace I have when i do `kubectl get pods,svc,rc --all-namespaces`

Changing kube-system to default in the yaml files is just getting me one step further but I am unable to access the UI and so on. so installing kube-system makes more sense however I dont know how to do it and any instructions on installing influxdb and grafana to get it up and running will be very helpful

[image: Displaying all pods and namespaces]

[image: InfluxDB seems like its working]

[image: Grafana link is not working for some reason but you can see the screen shot below that shows IP]

[image: cluster-info]

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you resolved?

Comment: Nope. Looks like I need to install DNS which is real pain. I still couldn't figure it out

Comment: I've tried to install too, but I cant. I want to try to substitute all domain with the IP. I let you know :)

Answer (score 1):

> I am using latest version of kubernetes version 1.0.1

FYI, the latest version is [v1.2.3](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases/tag/v1.2.3).

> ... it says kube-system not found

You can create the kube-system namespace by running 
`kubectl create namespace kube-system`.

Hopefully once you've created the kube-system namespace the rest of the instructions will work.

Comment: Thanks that got me one step closer but I still can't get grafana up and running. Please see the screen shots that I attached just now.

Comment: I can't tell much from the screen shots (sorry). Can you add some text about what you are seeing and where it diverges from the instructions?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue deploying grafana/influxdb.   So we dug into it:

Per https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/blob/master/docs/influxdb.md since we don’t have an external load balancer, we changed the port type on the grafana service to NodePort which made it accessible at port 30397.

Then looked at the controller configuration here: https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/blob/master/deploy/kube-config/influxdb/influxdb-grafana-controller.yaml and noticed the comment about using the api-server proxy which we wouldn’t be doing by exposing the NodePort, so we deleted the GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL environment variable from the config.  At that point Grafana at least seemed to be running, but it looked like it was having trouble reaching influxdb.

We then changed the datasource to use localhost instead of monitoring-influxd and was able to connect.  We're getting data on the cluster usage now, though individual pod data doesn’t seem to be working.